# Replace variable in expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regexp to find and replace a variable in python expression in string format. I don't want the 'var' replaced to be the part of another function or variable name. (I banned the solution using if 'var' in expr and expr.replace("var", etc.)).

So, I check the previous characters (allowed) and the following characters(allowed) with the following regexp:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(^var)(?=\+|\-|\*|\/| |$)|(?<=\+|\=|\[|\-|\*|\/|,| |\()var(?=\+|\-|\*|\/|$| |,|\))')
```

ô_O, it seems to be complicated but it works on the following test, replacing 'var' by '###'

```
expr     = ' var + variable + avar + var[x] + fun(var,variable) + fun2(variable, var, var1) + fun3(variable,var)+ var  -var/var+var*var*(var)'
expected = ' ### + variable + avar + var[x] + fun(###,variable) + fun2(variable, ###, var1) + fun3(variable,###)+ ###  -###/###+###*###*(###)'
```

I use regexp:

- to ckeck if 'var' is in expression
- to replace 'var' in expression
- to check if 'var' is not in expression after being replaced.

```js
if pattern.search(expr):
  new_expr = re.sub(pattern, '###', expr)  
  assert not pattern.search(new_expr), 'Replace failed'
```

I use the code a lot of time and I'm wondering if something simpler/faster exists ?

Comment: regex is not your tool of choice for parsing programming languages. Look into the ast module.

Comment: It seems odd that you are not replacing `var` in `var[x]` - is that intentional, or a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the pattern you need is: `r'\bvar\b'`, the `\b` is "border" which lets us define the full "string" we want to replace without replacing things like "variable"

However, upon testing your "expected" string, I found it had a mistake in it:

```
expected = ' ### + variable + avar + var[x] ' # <- this last 'var' should be ###
```

Anyway. Solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\bvar\b', '###', expr)
' ### + variable + avar + ###[x] + fun(###,variable) + fun2(variable, ###, var1) + fun3(variable,###)+ ###  -###/###+###*###*(###)'
```

Comment: it's not a mistake, I don't want the var to be a dict. It's looks like to be a border with exception.

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying, but valid code will not handle two variables with the same name in a namespace. `var` is `var` is `var`.

Comment: do I wrote a complex regexp to match a dump expression ? T_T. I'll check the code, I'll give you the answer.

Comment: Well, you're right, it's not a real situation. A better way to tests regexp is to use lists of expressions and lists of expected ones. The solution works with '\b'.

Comment: I wrote this sample to do not match the following situation : avar[x] => a###[x], even var[x] but var[x] will never exist in my code. '\b' is enough. thx.